# CSS Right to Left @keyframes transform:-100% to transform none

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations, right-to-left

I facing difficulty finding what causing the problem. And I appreciate your help. In the website I have set the html text direction right to left because the website in Arabic. And there is css animation which all are running normal. Except in the following condition:
When the html text direction is right to left and I'm browsing the website on mobile. Or using the device toggle option in google chrome. 
When the page loads, it loads on the div which is set -100% to the left, instead of loading on the content and the div which is -100% comes to the mid on the page. And that gives the illusion that the whole web page is coming from the right. I don't know how to solve this for mobile devices I'm thinking of viewports but I couldn't find a solution.
Here is the code for the webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="ar" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>RTL TEST SITE</title>
<style type="text/css">
.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes fadeInLeft {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  to {
    transform: none;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="rtl" >

    <div style="background:green;text-align:center;">
        <a>عنوان الصفحة</a>
    </div>

    <div class="fadeInLeft animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInLeft;">
        <h2>كلمات باللغة العربية تأتي من جهة اليسار</h2>
    </div>

    <p>فقرة مكتوبة باللغة العربي بين الكلمات المتحركة لتبين المشكلة ,,,فقرة مكتوبة باللغة العربي بين الكلمات المتحركة لتبين المشكلة ,,,فقرة مكتوبة باللغة العربي بين الكلمات المتحركة لتبين المشكلة ,,,فقرة مكتوبة باللغة العربي بين الكلمات المتحركة لتبين المشكلة ,,,فقرة مكتوبة باللغة العربي بين الكلمات المتحركة لتبين المشكلة ,,,فقرة مكتوبة </p>

    <div class="fadeInRight animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInRight;">
        <h2>كلمات باللغة العربية تأتي من جهة اليمين</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a link for the webpage
http://lotav.com/right2left.html
Please try it out on mobile device or use google chrome with setting the device toggle into mobile device and it will misbehave. And compare it with running the site on PC browser which will work normal.

And two pictures to explain what I mean. The first one when it loads normally on the PC and the second one when it loads abnormally on the mobile. [image: When it loads normal on PC] and [image: When it loads abnormally on the mobile]

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what is going on your website, I saw it so I tried using your code and apply it on the a default button and it worked without any problems. I added the class only.

```
.fade-in-left {
    animation: fadeInLeft ease 1s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft ease 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeInLeft ease 1s;
  -o-animation: fadeInLeft ease 1s;
  -ms-animation: fadeInLeft ease 1s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HiramRamirez/6qy9e52d/

Hopefully this may help you.

Comment: I have tried the code on the website. still the problem persist. on normal browser it shows no problem. Once you load the page on mobile or use Toggle device toolbar in google chrome you will find out the the title in centered on screen and web page is one coming from the right. thanks

Comment: I have edited the question so I hope you understand what I mean.